# asp.net jquery How to implement a jquery widget for a scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded a jquery scheduler and wanted to see it working. Unfortunately they dont have any info on how to implement it or get it working.

The Github page is [here](https://github.com/abstractmatter/Scheduler).

Its a widget however I am unsure how to make it work. I created an Asp.net mvc project and a page for it and thought it was to do with the id for a div but I had no luck.

How do I get this to work in an Asp.net mvc page?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is probably gonna get closed, but this is how you would use it, based on the source code:

```
$("#yourElement").scheduler({scheduleStart:'07:00',
            scheduleEnd:'20:00',
            overlap:true,
            newEventAdded:function($event, data){},
            eventChanged:function($event, data){},
            eventClicked:function($event, data){},
            initNewEvent:function(){
                return {};
            });
```